# Create a dictionary from a single line in a file

Tags: python, list, file, dictionary

I am currently writing a piece of code that takes a file with a list on one line, and a dictionary on another (See below). Is there a way to take a list or dictionary that was saved into a file in string form, and recreate that list/dict? I've tried other posts, but I don't think I'm searching for the right thing, as none of the threads seem to solve my question so far.

This is what the contents of the file looks like:
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
{'a': 1,'b': 2,'c': 3}

This is along the lines of what I thought would work(Obviously this is just an approximation)

```
location = input("Please input your file location")    
f.open(location, 'r')    
list = location(line1)    
dict = location(line2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To safely evaluate a string containing a Python literal you can use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval("[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]")
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> literal_eval("{'a': 1,'b': 2,'c': 3}")
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

To read and parse the first two lines of the file do:

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open(location) as f:
    L = literal_eval(f.readline())
    D = literal_eval(f.readline())
```

Comment: Can't he just use regular built in `eval` function instead of learning a new module?

Comment: @ytpillai: Using `eval()` is a bad practice since it can evaluate *arbitrary expressions*, not just literals, which may come from untrusted sources.